# Hibernate retrieve multiple collections efficiently

Tags: hibernate

I have a class called Invoice.
It has the following collections.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "taxInvoiceLinkId.invoice")
private List<TaxInvoiceLink>       taxLinks;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoiceCustomInfoLinkId.invoice")
private Set<InvoiceCustomInfoLink> customInfos = new LinkedHashSet(0);
```

To efficiently fetch these two collections (in terms of roundtrip and memory), should I do

**Option 1:** Join fetch both by

```
    Session session = SessionFactoryHandler.getSession();
    List result = null;
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery
                  (" From Invoice Inv left join fetch "+
                   " Inv.taxLinks left join fetch Inv.customInfos where 
                   invoice.id = 1");
    result = query.list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return result;
```

**Option 2:** execute as two statements

```
  Session session = SessionFactoryHandler.getSession();
    List result = null;
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery
                  (" From Invoice Inv left join fetch Inv.taxLinks
                       where invoice.id = 1" );
    result = query.list();

    query =  session.createQuery
                  (" From Invoice Inv left join fetch Inv.customInfos where 
                   invoice.id = 1");
    result = query.list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    return result;
```

Comment: You don't need to commit queries. Expense in queries is generally higher for network communication and SQL interpretation than for actual fetching results so 1 should generally be faster however it will yield a set of rows from the database with lots of nulls and a more complex query. That may be harder on the JPA provider but who knows without looking or testing.

Comment: If there are two tax links in the Invoice, Both the option 2 is executing two select queries, My FetchMode is SELECT and Batch Size is 10. Would you know what the reason could be

Answer (score 0):

Replace List with Set and add FetchType EAGER in mapping,

```
@Entity
Class Result{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "taxInvoiceLinkId.invoice",fetch=fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<TaxInvoiceLink>       taxLinks;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoiceCustomInfoLinkId.invoice",,fetch=fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<InvoiceCustomInfoLink> customInfos;
}
```

then retrieve your Entity using criteria,

```
Session session = SessionFactoryHandler.getSession();
List result = null;
session.beginTransaction();
Query query = session.createCriteria(Result.class);
List<Result> result = query.list();
```

Comment: Thanks Ajish, but I dont want to Eager fetch nor do I want to use criteria query.